# SQL Server - last accessed timestamp on rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which is used as a shared cache and is periodically trimmed based on whether the individual rows have been accessed recently (i.e. if the row hasn't been accessed in a week, it is deleted). At the moment I have a `LastAccessed date` column which I update every time I access the row.

At the moment I'm doing this by selected with an `UPDATE` query, and using the `OUTPUT` clause to actually select the data. However, this is quite slow (a typical query takes a few seconds) and I'm concerned about locking and concurrent access since many processes can access this table at once and they all need to update the last-accessed timestamp.

Is there a better way to do this? I know about `ROWVERSION`, but this appears to be for updates, not selects. Once a row is written to the table the date, it is never changed (apart from the `LastAccessed` column, at the moment). There also doesn't appear to be any `SELECT`-based triggers which I can use.

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to fix the performance issue would be to change your code to update the record only when the `LastAccessed date` is older than say 24hours. This will greatly reduce the number of updates that occur on your table.

A better approach overall might be to normalize out the `LastAccessed date` to a separate table so that you don't have to re-write the entire row every time you read it (generally when you do an update the entire row is re-written *somewhere*). In addition, you could make this updates table a heap where you just continue to insert new records to it rather than updating a previous record, this would prevent any locks from occurring.

Combining these two will address your performance issues unless your data is accessed very infrequently. This will also address the general "it locks the whole table" problem.

For reference `ROWVERSION` and `TIMESTAMP` won't do what you want because not only do they only update on `UPDATE` commands, they do not map back to any 'datetime' value. It's not advised but you can do ad-hoc `ROWVERSION to date` mapping using a table where you just write `GETDATE()` and a `ROWVERSION` (this works since rowversion is unique for the database).

Comment: Good answer. In addition, if you can buffer multiple updates in your client, and issue them periodically in a single, batched transaction, it will also help.

Comment: Just to expand upon or clarify the rowversion to getdate decoder table option.  This would require a scheduled run to capture the @@DBTS value at the points in time your application requires. i.e. run it after every nightly batch to record the point where your next batch job needs to look back to for changes. Use a varbinary(8) datatype to store this value, as the timestamp datatype would not be a stable value.

Comment: WIth the heap idea, wouldn't this cause a lot of extra reads and overhead on sorting to get the most recent row? Would you set up some periodic job to delete the old data?

Answer (score 0):

A `ROWVERSION` column does get updated automatically on each update - but it does **not** contain any information about date or time of that update (it's **only** a counter - no relationship with date/time at all!).

There - unfortunately - is currently no automatic "out-of-the-box" solution in SQL Server for this - there's no magic way to keep track of the last date/time of an update. If you need that info - you need to keep it yourself. Only other option: use a `ON UPDATE` trigger that would handle this for you - so you don't have to remember doing it on each `UPDATE` statement...

**Update:** ah - okay, so you want to update this during `SELECT` - that's absolutely not possible at the moment in SQL Server - there's simply no `ON SELECT` trigger mechanism available, so I don't think you can track "last accessed" in terms of `SELECT` other than manually doing this yourself for each `SELECT` statement you have.....

Comment: If I understand the question correctly the problem is not with updates (that should indeed be solved w/ triggers) but with `SELECT` statements. The `LastAccessed` should be updated when something from the table is selected.

Comment: I'm not really UPDATE-ing though - I'm SELECT-ing. The only reason I mention updates is that is my current method of updating the 'last accessed' column. I was hoping there is a better way, and perhaps a way that doesn't involve locking big chunks of a table while other processes are doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible by native Sql Server tools, **but** you can implement is in a very restricting manner by performing your own data access thru Stored Procedures

Answer (score 0):

This is very difficult, but it is possible.

- Create a [server side trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191443%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which filters on this table (over the field object_id) and write the result to a table
- Write an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the trace result table which fires a TSQL or CLR proc that takes the trace text and timestamp as parameter.
- Parse the trace text and replace the `SELECT xxx` part by `UPDATE myTable SET lastAccessed = @timestamp`
- Execute the resulting TSQL statement.

This will work, but does it mean you should do it? If you wish to use a caching system, I think you are better off by using a real cache. SQL Server provides full ACID which is a too heavy requirement for a cache. (When the server crashes you usually don't mind that your cache needs to be repopulated)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 may be you might want to check out "Change Tracking" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx